# Can you produce a dynamically generated field in MySQL at the server lever?

Tags: mysql

We have an older system that's being replaced piecemeal. The people who originally designed it broke US telephone numbers for our clients up into three fields: phone_part_1, phone_part_2, and phone_part_3, corresponding to US Areacodes, Exchanges, and Phone Numbers respectively.

We're transitioning to use a single field, phone_number, to hold all 10 digits. But, because some pieces of the system will continue to reference the older fields, we've been forced to double up for the moment.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use MySQL built-in features to reroute requests for the old fields (both on read and write) to the newer field without having to change the old code (which is in a language nobody here is comfortable in anyhow.) So that:

```
SELECT phone_part_1 FROM users;
```

Would end up the same as

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( phone_number, 1, 3 );
```

To be clear, I want to do this *without* manipulating the individual queries. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW users AS
  SELECT SUBSTRING( phone_number, 1, 3 ) AS phone_number, ... FROM real_users;
```

Then you can query it as if it were a table:

```
SELECT phone_number FROM users;
```

But that would require your "real" table to be stored with a distinct table name. You can't make a view with the same name as an existing table.

When you're ready to really replace the table with the new structure, then you can use RENAME TABLE to change tables as a quick action (no table restructure required).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into views? A view will take the place of a new table for now, providing a way to have your new structure, but still access the data in the original tables. Once you are ready for your final move, you can implement new tables and do a mass conversion of any remaining data you haven't done yet. Or you can go in reverse, which is what it sounds like you really would prefer.

Create your new table, convert your data, and set up a view that mimics the old structure.

Views in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html